# R markdown: how to print dataframe compactly

Tags: r, dplyr, markdown, knitr

I am using `knitr::kable` to print my dataframes, but sometimes they are too big. Is there any simple way to print them compactly with scrollbar?

For example, I do:

```
knitr::kable(mtcars)
```

How could I add scrolling by condition (for example, if `nrow > 10` and/or `ncol > 10`)?

P.S. `DT::datatable` doesn't work for big `ncol`:

[image]

I need exactly scrolling interface.

Comment: You can use a DT::datatable()

Comment: @Florian, unfortunately it doesn't work correctly if there are a lot of data

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? I used `DT::datatable()` with quite of bit of data before and it wasn't a problem. `DT::datatable(mtcars)` certainly works.

Comment: @JBGruber, added an example in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add scrollbars. For example, with `kableExtra` or `DT`:

#### R Markdown

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
```

Some very wide data:

```{r}
df <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars)
```

With `kableExtra`:

```{r}

kable(df) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "200px")
```

Or with `DT`:

```{r}
DT::datatable(
  df,
  height = 200,
  options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
)
```
````

#### output

[image]